# ME: Andromeda Savegame error

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

I started Playing ME:Andromeda a few days before the patch and now I updated it via Origin. I played 25h as Sara and completed the main Storyline and just finished Elaaden.

When loading a saved game (happens at every savegame) or pressing continue, it pops an error:

(roughly translated into English from German)

> **Savegame-Error**
>
> Your savegame couldn't be loaded. You're connected with content that's
>   not installed anymore:
>
> **Deluxe Edition-Pack**
>
> Please re-install this content and try again.

I have the standard issue with the space armor-DLC. What does this mean and how can I fix this? Anyone also encountered this?

It's a beautiful game and I'd like to enjoy the rest of the game with my old character.

Comment: Try re-downloading the DLC.